# Find Matrix A such that A{1,0,0} = {5,-3,1}

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

]i started this problem but i'm not able to write out the equations. For example does 1=5?  i just help to start the actual problem... thank you

Find matrix A such as A{1,0,0} = {5,-3,1} A{0,1,0} = {1,-1,4} A{0,0,1} = {3,3,3}

Image contains the problem.

Comment: Please typeset your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can use it to write this: $ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: One such matrix is $$A=\begin{bmatrix}5&1&3\\-3&-1&3\\1&4&3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Hint: the columns are the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are given

$$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf v_1,\quad A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf v_2,\quad A\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf v_3$$

Or placing them horizontally next to each other,

$$\begin{align*}
A\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}&=
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1&\mathbf v_2&\mathbf v_3\end{bmatrix}\\
AI_3 &=
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1&\mathbf v_2&\mathbf v_3\end{bmatrix}\\
A &=
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1&\mathbf v_2&\mathbf v_3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: So, the matrix you gave in the comments is also the only such matrix.